# Как мне можно прочитать все секторы памяти на флешке C/C++

Tags: c++, c, winapi

Мне необходимо считывать сектор памяти и как-то его зашифровать. Я понимаю что делается это как-то через `ReadFileA` `CreateFile` и функции на подобии этого, только мне немного непонятно, как это можно реализовать. Я нашел код, который считывает самый первый сектор, но как итерироваться дальше, я не знаю.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Получить "файл" на диск

```
int retCode = 0;
BYTE sector[512];
DWORD bytesRead;
HANDLE device = NULL;
int numSector = 5;

device = CreateFile(L"\\\\.\\C:",    // Drive to open
                    GENERIC_READ,           // Access mode
                    FILE_SHARE_READ|FILE_SHARE_WRITE,        // Share Mode
                    NULL,                   // Security Descriptor
                    OPEN_EXISTING,          // How to create
                    0,                      // File attributes
                    NULL);                  // Handle to template
```

И читай  в цикле

```
do {
  if (ReadFile(device, sector, 512, &bytesRead, NULL)) {
    // сектор в переменной sector. bytesRead - сколько байтов прочлось
  } else {
    // тут отработать ошибку
    break;
  }
} while (bytesRead);
```

Comment: Как нам заполнить переменную sector тем что нужно? Мне просто пока не очень дается низкоуровневые функции и я немного не понимаю как они работают.

Comment: Сектор заполняется содержимым диска функцией readfile.

Comment: Образно, если у меня флешка на 8 гигов, то он по 512 байт будет считать вечность, как нам пропускать пустые сектора, как бы я не пытался не выходит

Comment: И как нам можно пропускать пустые сектора ?

Comment: чтоб пропускать пустые - читай папку на диске, а не сам диск посекторно. для ускорения вычитывай по 10мегабайт вместо 512.

Comment: Как понять, читать папку на диске, а не сам диск. Разве когда мы открываем диск через CreateFile мы не спускаемся "ниже" чем папки. И если считывать по 10 мб. как нам гарантировать что, мы ничего не упустили. Потому что моя цель заключается в том, чтобы реализовать FDE. И у меня на этот счет есть 2 идеи. Шифровать все сектора, или зашифровать MBR. Ни первый, ни второй метод, я не понимаю как реализовывать.

Comment: Так, же я нашел реализацию итерации по секторам через `SetFilePointer` но мне кажется или она работает немного некорректно

Answer (score 0):

Нет. Сектора и файлы – это вообще разные уровни абстракции. Вам нужна функция для доступа к внешней памяти на физическом уровне.

Comment: В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша [репутация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); на данный момент, пожалуйста, [внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/800039)

Comment: А с чего Вы взяли, что я помню наизусть все низкоуровневые функции? Раздел документации я указал. Это даже если забыть, что в вопросе не указана даже файловая система, от которой решение зависит полностью.

Comment: В результате вы предлагаете вместо ответа "Найдите то, не знаю что". Такие ответы здесь никому не нужны.

Comment: Нет. Я обозначил, что искать.